# How to use Windows 10/11's Dark Theme in C# WinForm controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, darkmode

I'm trying to make a C# WinForm App with Dark Mode ability.

Windows already have 'dark themed controls' like this:
[image: NOTE: This is made with AutoHotkey]
(NOTE: This is made with AutoHotkey)
And I also want to use this.

I've searched some libraries for this:

- [DarkUI](https://github.com/RobinPerris/DarkUI)
  This uses *outdated* WinForm controls which misses few properties that should be available.
  It is rather 'Gray UI' but it is far better than white controls.

  - [AltUI](https://github.com/kran27/AltUI)
    Fork of DarkUI, but it tried to mimic Windows' Dark Theme as similar as posible.
    But I have to manually compile the library before using it because it hasn't been on NuGet yet.
- [DarkNet](https://github.com/Aldaviva/DarkNet)
  It only handles Title Bar.
  I want to have 'dark themed controls' too.

I know that there isn't some kind of 'magic method' for dark themed controls.

But while searching code for 'dark themed controls', I found *working* AutoHotkey v2 code.

```
; Source: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=115952
DarkColors := Map("Background", "0x202020", "Controls", "0x404040", "Font", "0xE0E0E0")
TextBGBrush := DllCall("gdi32\CreateSolidBrush", "UInt", DarkColors["Background"], "Ptr")
SetMenuAttr() {
  global DarkColors
  if (VerCompare(A_OSVersion, "10.0.17763") >= 0) {
    DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE := 19
    if (VerCompare(A_OSVersion, "10.0.18985") >= 0) {
      DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE := 20
    }
    uxtheme := DllCall("kernel32\GetModuleHandle", "Str", "uxtheme", "Ptr")
    SetPreferredAppMode := DllCall("kernel32\GetProcAddress", "Ptr", uxtheme, "Ptr", 135, "Ptr")
    FlushMenuThemes := DllCall("kernel32\GetProcAddress", "Ptr", uxtheme, "Ptr", 136, "Ptr")

    DllCall("dwmapi\DwmSetWindowAttribute", "Ptr", A_ScriptHwnd, "Int", DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE, "Int*", True, "Int", 4)
    DllCall(SetPreferredAppMode, "Int", 2) ; 0=Default, 1=AllowDark, 2=ForceDark, 3=ForceLight, 4=Max
    DllCall(FlushMenuThemes)
  }
}
SetWinAttr(GuiObj) {
  global DarkColors
  if (VerCompare(A_OSVersion, "10.0.17763") >= 0) {
    DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE := 19
    if (VerCompare(A_OSVersion, "10.0.18985") >= 0) {
      DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE := 20
    }
    uxtheme := DllCall("kernel32\GetModuleHandle", "Str", "uxtheme", "Ptr")
    SetPreferredAppMode := DllCall("kernel32\GetProcAddress", "Ptr", uxtheme, "Ptr", 135, "Ptr")
    FlushMenuThemes := DllCall("kernel32\GetProcAddress", "Ptr", uxtheme, "Ptr", 136, "Ptr")

    DllCall("dwmapi\DwmSetWindowAttribute", "Ptr", GuiObj.Hwnd, "Int", DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE, "Int*", True, "Int", 4)
    DllCall(SetPreferredAppMode, "Int", 2) ; 0=Default, 1=AllowDark, 2=ForceDark, 3=ForceLight, 4=Max
    DllCall(FlushMenuThemes)
    GuiObj.BackColor := DarkColors["Background"]
  }
}
SetWinTheme(GuiObj) {
  static GWL_WNDPROC := -4
  static GWL_STYLE := -16
  static ES_MULTILINE := 0x0004
  static LVM_GETTEXTCOLOR := 0x1023
  static LVM_SETTEXTCOLOR := 0x1024
  static LVM_GETTEXTBKCOLOR := 0x1025
  static LVM_SETTEXTBKCOLOR := 0x1026
  static LVM_GETBKCOLOR := 0x1000
  static LVM_SETBKCOLOR := 0x1001
  static LVM_GETHEADER := 0x101F
  static GetWindowLong := A_PtrSize = 8 ? "GetWindowLongPtr" : "GetWindowLong"
  static SetWindowLong := A_PtrSize = 8 ? "SetWindowLongPtr" : "SetWindowLong"
  Init := False
  LV_Init := False

  Mode_Explorer := "DarkMode_Explorer"
  Mode_CFD := "DarkMode_CFD"
  Mode_ItemsView := "DarkMode_ItemsView"

  for hWnd, GuiCtrlObj in GuiObj {
    switch GuiCtrlObj.Type {
      case "Button", "CheckBox", "ListBox", "UpDown", "Text":
      {
        DllCall("uxtheme\SetWindowTheme", "Ptr", GuiCtrlObj.hWnd, "Str", Mode_Explorer, "Ptr", 0)
      }
      case "ComboBox", "DDL":
      {
        DllCall("uxtheme\SetWindowTheme", "Ptr", GuiCtrlObj.hWnd, "Str", Mode_CFD, "Ptr", 0)
      }
      case "Edit":
      {
        if (DllCall("user32\" . GetWindowLong, "Ptr", GuiCtrlObj.hWnd, "Int", GWL_STYLE) & ES_MULTILINE) {
          DllCall("uxtheme\SetWindowTheme", "Ptr", GuiCtrlObj.hWnd, "Str", Mode_Explorer, "Ptr", 0)
        } else {
          DllCall("uxtheme\SetWindowTheme", "Ptr", GuiCtrlObj.hWnd, "Str", Mode_CFD, "Ptr", 0)
        }
      }
      case "ListView":
      {
        if !(LV_Init) {
          static LV_TEXTCOLOR := SendMessage(LVM_GETTEXTCOLOR, 0, 0, GuiCtrlObj.hWnd)
          static LV_TEXTBKCOLOR := SendMessage(LVM_GETTEXTBKCOLOR, 0, 0, GuiCtrlObj.hWnd)
          static LV_BKCOLOR := SendMessage(LVM_GETBKCOLOR, 0, 0, GuiCtrlObj.hWnd)
          LV_Init := True
        }
        GuiCtrlObj.Opt("-Redraw")
        SendMessage(LVM_SETTEXTCOLOR, 0, DarkColors["Font"], GuiCtrlObj.hWnd)
        SendMessage(LVM_SETTEXTBKCOLOR, 0, DarkColors["Background"], GuiCtrlObj.hWnd)
        SendMessage(LVM_SETBKCOLOR, 0, DarkColors["Background"], GuiCtrlObj.hWnd)
        DllCall("uxtheme\SetWindowTheme", "Ptr", GuiCtrlObj.hWnd, "Str", Mode_Explorer, "Ptr", 0)
        ; To color the selection - scrollbar turns back to normal
        ;DllCall("uxtheme\SetWindowTheme", "Ptr", GuiCtrlObj.hWnd, "Str", Mode_ItemsView, "Ptr", 0)
        LV_Header := SendMessage(LVM_GETHEADER, 0, 0, GuiCtrlObj.hWnd)
        DllCall("uxtheme\SetWindowTheme", "Ptr", LV_Header, "Str", Mode_ItemsView, "Ptr", 0)
        GuiCtrlObj.Opt("+Redraw")
      }
    }
  }
  if !(Init) {
    ; https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/CallbackCreate.htm#ExSubclassGUI
    global WindowProcNew := CallbackCreate(WindowProc)  ; Avoid fast-mode for subclassing.
    global WindowProcOld := DllCall("user32\" . SetWindowLong, "Ptr", GuiObj.Hwnd, "Int", GWL_WNDPROC, "Ptr", WindowProcNew, "Ptr")
    Init := True
  }
}
WindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam) {
  critical
  static WM_CTLCOLOREDIT := 0x0133
  static WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX := 0x0134
  static WM_CTLCOLORBTN := 0x0135
  static WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC := 0x0138
  static DC_BRUSH := 18

  switch uMsg {
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT, WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX:
    {
      DllCall("gdi32\SetTextColor", "Ptr", wParam, "UInt", DarkColors["Font"])
      DllCall("gdi32\SetBkColor", "Ptr", wParam, "UInt", DarkColors["Controls"])
      DllCall("gdi32\SetDCBrushColor", "Ptr", wParam, "UInt", DarkColors["Controls"], "UInt")
      return DllCall("gdi32\GetStockObject", "Int", DC_BRUSH, "Ptr")
    }
    case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
    {
      DllCall("gdi32\SetDCBrushColor", "Ptr", wParam, "UInt", DarkColors["Background"], "UInt")
      return DllCall("gdi32\GetStockObject", "Int", DC_BRUSH, "Ptr")
    }
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
      DllCall("gdi32\SetTextColor", "Ptr", wParam, "UInt", DarkColors["Font"])
      DllCall("gdi32\SetBkColor", "Ptr", wParam, "UInt", DarkColors["Background"])
      return TextBGBrush
    }
  }
  return DllCall("user32\CallWindowProc", "Ptr", WindowProcOld, "Ptr", hwnd, "UInt", uMsg, "Ptr", wParam, "Ptr", lParam)
}
```

Also I found [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72988434) which seems to use similar way (foreach every controls) for setting dark theme for controls.

Is there any other library for 'dark themed control' that I missed? Or is there any nicer way to set dark theme to controls?

PS.
I personally don't want to use WPF even though it has nice ['dark theme'](https://github.com/AngryCarrot789/WPFDarkTheme) because I couldn't figure out how to place controls freely like in WinForm.

Comment: Presumably its easier to understand WPF then getting theming correctly working in Winforms even if you define working as somewhere around 90% of the time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems like you've put in some effort exploring various options for implementing a dark theme in your C# WinForm app. The provided AutoHotkey v2 code demonstrates an approach using Windows API calls to achieve a dark mode for controls.

If you're looking for other libraries or approaches, one option to consider is using the MetroFramework library, which provides a Metro-style user interface, including a dark theme. You can find it on NuGet, and it's compatible with WinForms.

To use MetroFramework, you can install it using NuGet Package Manager Console:

```bash
Install-Package MetroFramework
```

Then, you can apply the dark theme to your form by setting the `Style` property:

```cs
this.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Black;
```

This library might offer a more convenient way to achieve a dark theme for your WinForm controls without having to manually handle each control.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

https://github.com/edgars-pivovarenoks/winforms-modernui

Forked from archived and bumped up to .NET 8.0. Might get you on the right track. This frameworks let's you switch Themes dynamically and has most common controls in the toolbox. Has built in Themes, but you can easily adjust it to your own needs.

This is pure WinForms framework emulating style and feel of modern Apps. Scaling might be an issue though.